# Change the RootPage

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, ionic2, firebase-authentication, ionic3

I am new to Ionic and I have a problem trying to push a rootpage on Ionic 3

On app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { LoginPage } from '../pages/login/login';
import { LoggedinPage } from '../pages/loggedin/loggedin';
import firebase from 'firebase';

@Component({
   template: `<ion-nav [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>`
 })
export class MyApp {

rootPage: any;

 var state = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    this.rootPage = LoginPage;
    //console.log(this.rootPage);
    //from here i can see that the this.rootpage is defined.
  } else {
    this.rootPage = LoggedinPage;
  }

   console.log(this.rootPage);
   //the rootpage is not defined outside of the funtion
});
 }
```

What I want to do, id to redirect users that are already loggedin to the LoggedIn Page.

Comment: check my answer...

Answer (score 0):

in app.component.ts

`rootPage: any;` is mistake, can you use `rootPage: any = 'targetPage';`

if you use menu `rootPage: any = 'menuPage';` and chose rootPage in menuPage.ts ;

```
export class MenuPage {

  rootPage = 'targetPage';
```

Answer (score 0):

> Need to change code following manner:

```
import {Component, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {Nav} from 'ionic-angular';
import { LoginPage } from '../pages/login/login';
import { LoggedinPage } from '../pages/loggedin/loggedin';
import firebase from 'firebase';

@Component({
   template: `<ion-nav [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>`
 })
export class MyApp {

  rootPage: any;

  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;

 var state = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    this.nav.setRoot(LoginPage);
    //console.log(this.rootPage);
    //from here i can see that the this.rootpage is defined.
  } else {
    this.nav.setRoot(LoggedinPage);
  }

   console.log(this.rootPage);
   //the rootpage is not defined outside of the funtion
});
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set userdata after login and clear on logout. and while setting rootPage you can check whether userdata does exist or not. And on initializeApp function of app.component.ts

```
  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {

      this.rootPage = localStorage.getItem('userData') ? MyDashboardPage : LoginPage;
    });
  }
```